# Need a quick clarification about this Coset notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm not looking for an answer to the actual problem, just what this notation could plausibly mean.

Let $G$=$R$ ⊕ $R$, and fix positive real numbers $a$ and $b$. Let $H$=<>. Give a geometric interpretation of the cosets of $H$.

What is that <<$a$,$b$>> ? I've never seen that notation before.

Thanks for any and all input!

Again, thank you all for the input! Much appreciated.

Comment: Subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$ ?

Comment: The subgroup generated by the element $(a,b)$?

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle,\rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Comment: I've also seen double angle brackets used to denote the normal subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$, i.e. the normal closure of $\langle a,b \rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely that $\langle a, b \rangle$ is intended to denote the ordered pair $(a, b)$, and that $\langle x \rangle$ is intended to denote the subgroup generated by $x$.

Therefore, $\langle \langle a, b \rangle \rangle$ is the subgroup generated by the ordered pair $(a, b)$.

Comment: So a left coset could potentially look like (a+b)(H)?

Comment: In this instance, the cosets would look like $(a, b) H$. I should add that Matt B's comment of "normal closure" seems a bit more likely than my answer.